# Grouping of pairs in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to group (a,b) and (b,a) into one group (a,b) in SQL

For e.g the following set

```
SELECT 'a' AS Col1, 'b' AS Col2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', 'a'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'c', 'd'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', 'c'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', 'd'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', 'c'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'd', 'a'
```

should yield

```
Col1 | Col2
a       b
c       d
a       c
a       d
b       c
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group by a case statement that selects the pairs in alphabetical order:

```
select case when col1 < col2 then col1 else col2 end as col1,
case when col1 < col2 then col2 else col1 end as col2
from (
    select 'a' as col1, 'b' as col2
    union all
    select 'b', 'a'
    union all
    select 'c', 'd'
    union all
    select 'a', 'c'
    union all
    select 'a', 'd'
    union all
    select 'b', 'c'
    union all
    select 'd', 'a'
) t group by case when col1 < col2 then col1 else col2 end,
case when col1 < col2 then col2 else col1 end
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/6977

If you simply want unique values (as opposed to a grouping for aggregation) then you can use `distinct` instead of `group by`

```
select distinct case when col1 < col2 then col1 else col2 end as col1,
case when col1 < col2 then col2 else col1 end as col2
from (
    select 'a' as col1, 'b' as col2
    union all
    select 'b', 'a'
    union all
    select 'c', 'd'
    union all
    select 'a', 'c'
    union all
    select 'a', 'd'
    union all
    select 'b', 'c'
    union all
    select 'd', 'a'
) t
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you could use a `UNION` to achieve this:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 'a' AS Col1, 'b' AS Col2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b', 'a'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'c', 'd'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a', 'c'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a', 'd'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b', 'c'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'd', 'a')
SELECT col1, col2 FROM cte WHERE col1 < col2 OR col1 IS NULL
UNION
SELECT col2, col1 FROM cte WHERE col1 >= col2 OR col2 IS NULL
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/7003)

Note that a `UNION` removes duplicates.

If you don't have `NULL` values, you can of course omit the `OR` part in the `WHERE` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

By value, (a, b) doesn't equal to (b, a). If you want to treat them the same, you're creating new key column(s) for each row. The overall logic would be

```
WITH TableWithNewKey
(
    SELECT <original columns>, <new columns as key>
    FROM originaltable
)
SELECT <new columns as key>, Aggregate(...)
FROM TableWithNewKey
GROUP BY <new columns as key>
```

In your case, `<new columns as key>` is to convert (b, a) to (a, b). It can be case statement to swap a and b or other functions. This form applies to any number of columns and other equality comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
select col1, col2 from table 
except 
select col2, col2 from table where col2 > col1
```